# Problems with KWallet after resuming from suspend

Tags: wireless, 12.10, kubuntu, suspend, kwallet

I am running Kubuntu 12.10 with all of the recent updates installed and configured on  a Dell Latitude E6500.  If I suspend my laptop either through closing the lid or hitting the function key, upon resume KWallet does not want to unlock.  I know I'm typing the password correctly and I know it's the right password because it unlocks once I reboot the machine.

Because KWallet isn't unlocked my wireless won't reconnect.  I have to logout and log back into the computer to re-unlock KWallet and then can connect to my wireless.

This seems to be a relatively new problem, following some form of update. I'm not sure what happened. Any ideas?

Comment: I have a similar issue. When I don't unlock wallet after login quick enough it behaves like you describe. I only have to logout/login and open wallet quick to make the system behave behave again.

Comment: Yeah I can login and logout to reset this, so I will edit this question to make sure it states that a reboot isn't necessary to get this to work right

Answer (score 1):

Go into System Settings -> Account Details -> KDE Wallet. Make sure the Wallet isn't set up to close automatically.

Then System Settings -> Network Connections. You need to have "System Connection" + "Connect Automatically" enabled for each of your connections Wireless & Wired in order for your connection to return automatically.